# Changing a .keystore password

Tags: certificate, keystore

I have the following steps:

1) Open Terminal and cd to where your .keystore is located

2) keytool -storepasswd -new NEWPASSWORD -keystore YOURKEYSTORE.keystore

3) enter your current password

My question is instead of doing step 3, how can I do it with a keytool command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close but not quite, eventually I figured out that the password should be changed in two locations, keypasswd & storepasswd:

1) keytool -storepass XXX -keypasswd -keypass XXXXX -new XXXX -keystore "c:\temp\XXXX.keystore" -alias XXX

2) keytool -storepass XXX -storepasswd -new XXXX -keystore "c:\temp\XXX.keystore" -alias XXX

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `-storepass`

> keytool -storepasswd -new {NEW_PASSWORD} -keystore {KEYSTORE.keystore} -**storepass {OLD_PASSWORD}**